# Q: How to join static and moving circles with a line

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

My scene contains three circles – two circles are static and one is constantly moving around the bigger one. I need to connect a moving circle with a central one such that a connection line is pinned to both circles (I want the line to move along with the moving circle).

[image]

The line is a `SKShapeNode` with a `CGPath` connecting centres of circles *A* and *B*. Circle *A* is moving whereas circle *B* is static. I've tried to connect the line's physics body with the *A*'s physics body via `SKPhysicsJointPin` and do the same for *B*. But this doesn't work as wanted.

```
let joint = SKPhysicsJointPin.joint(withBodyA: circleA.physicsBody!, bodyB: line.physicsBody!, anchor: circleA.position)
let joint2 = SKPhysicsJointPin.joint(withBodyA: circleB.physicsBody!, bodyB: line.physicsBody!, anchor: circleB.position)

physicsWorld.add(joint)
physicsWorld.add(joint2)
```

Line is dynamic and the world has gravity set up.

How should the nodes be joint?

Comment: How are you moving Circle A around the center of Circle B?

Comment: I use the `SKAction.follow()` method with a `UIBezierPath` (its `CGPath` wrapper).

Comment: If you use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243964/follow-a-path-inverse) move the sprite around Point B, you can draw a line from the center to the Circle A and rotate the entire system.